# Is it acceptable to post a question taken from Quora?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I would like to ask on [Space.SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/) exactly [this question](http://www.quora.com/Did-Neil-Armstrong-and-Buzz-Aldrin-have-instructions-of-what-to-do-if-they-couldnt-take-off-from-the-moon).

Is it acceptable?

Comment: Remember that SE content is licenced under http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/. This means that you have to have the rights to the content you post for them to have the rights. Also remember that you need to attribute the question content to the Quora question.

Answer (score 5):

Well, try not to make it an ***exact duplicate***; that would be wrong.

Try to reword the question in your own way and make it as original as it can be. Then make a little note on the bottom like:

> Inspiration comes from: [link](http://www.quora.com/Did-Neil-Armstrong-and-Buzz-Aldrin-have-instructions-of-what-to-do-if-they-couldnt-take-off-from-the-moon)

Of course, you could change link to something like Quora question or something to do with Quora. As said by Patrick Hofman, try asking this in the meta site for Space.SE.

So yes.

Comment: I forgot your name... I did edit the post to include your name

Answer (score 5):

First: yes. You can ask questions posted somewhere else here if the license of that other site allows it (generally it does if you are the author). You do want to make it unique, so don't just copy/paste it. (Or remove it from the other site if it wasn't answered there for example)

Second: on the actual question: You had better ask this on their own meta:  [meta.space.stackexchange.com](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/). They have a better understanding on what is on-topic there and what isn't. From what I can read in their [help](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) it is on-topic.